# Refresh All opened tab in a website at once - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have the auto logout function in my website and 30 seconds before the auto logout pop up will appear and we can press the continue button to continue the session.

But when I open multiple tabs in the browser and if I press continue button it only continue the session of currently open tab and other tabs are keeping logout.I want to keep other pages also live when I press the continue button in an one tab.

Can you please help me?Is there any code for that in javascript.?

Comment: You can local storage, cookies, memcached or redis?